# Angular data is not updated for user using the observable

Tags: angular, firebase

I have an issue in updating the user data on the Firebase data update

```
id : "59a53660-98a0-4bb0-9dba-09fbb090ffd2"
name : "diigiv"
openTableSession :"dd509238-9967-45d3-ab28-ee5465400d6e"
phoneNumber :"852369885"
```

This is my data in the Firebase. The open table session field get updated as soon as I clicked on the link for a particular table. But on the view page it is still showing the old data.

```
const userSub = this.auth.currentUserInstance$.subscribe((user) => {
  this.currentUser = user;
  console.log('first')
});
```

Comment: A "observable" **not** put a "spy" in the dbs to look the changes. When you update the dbs, you should ask again about the dbs

Comment: firebase is used for real-time update. The rest of the app is working with this logic that if the data is updated in the firebase it is updated on the app immediately